# Project Online OData Source - SSIS

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio, odata, project-online, pwa

I have an MS project online environment and I want to replicate all data from online to our SQL servers. I found [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-odata/dn720853(v=office.15)) to do this with VS2012. I'm using VS2019 and SSDT, SSIS, SSAS extensions, and SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK installed on my local computer. But I'm getting this error while I try to access the PWA source using OData connection manager. How can I solve this problem and replicate all data from online to on-prem servers?

```
===================================

Test connection failed

===================================

msoidcliL.dll (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.ODataConnectionManager)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.OData.ShimSharePointOnlineCredentials..ctor(String userName, SecureString password)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.OData.UI.ODataConnectionManagerForm.GetWebRequest()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.OData.UI.ODataConnectionManagerForm.TestConnectionMiddle(Object callback)
```

[image]

[image]